# XMLHttpRequest (POST) is ignored in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I use an XMLHttpRequest to post data to a server. It looks like this:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'http://myurl/post';

  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            leaveEditMode();
        } else {
           initOverlay('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
        }
     }
  };
  xhr.send(
      'StringName=' + $activeElement.dataset.name + '&' +
      'Text=' + encodeURIComponent($activeElement.innerHTML) + '&' +
      'Language=' + userLanguage
  );
```

This code works perfectly fine in Chrome, FireFox and Opera. But in IE11 it does not. There are no errors and I get status code 200 back from the request. But the data is not being posted. Seems like the request is ignored.

Any ideas? I tried an anti-cache-header - nothing.

Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: If you get a status back, the request has to go somewhere. What does the server side see?

Comment: `AjaxRequest.getInstance()` seems ominous. What's it doing?

Comment: AjaxRequest.getInstance() returns a new XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: Do you execute your code from file:// protocol instead of http://? IE11 has problems with XMLHttpRequest on file:// protocol.

Comment: On http:// your example just works fine in IE11, I tried.

Comment: Is it the same domain? Is it going from https to http? What appears in the console?

Comment: It seemed to have been a problem with HTTPS. But the console did not display any errors. Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, simple enough, the parameter userLanguage was not set right and the server didn't send an appropriate response.